# Thoughts on best practices for user content management

Tags: users

I have a website where I need specific user roles (restaurant owner) to edit specific content type (their respective restaurant profile and services) which has a node reference field to the main restaurant profile.

I've been developing a website before where I needed to change the author of the node so this user could edit (with right permission) however, I'm sure there should be a better automated practice.

I am thinking of using Profile 2, with node reference user to a specific content type.

Any ideas on what's best to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

If nodes are supposed to match 1:1, why not to make them one node, with different displays and access to different fields?
Or, actually, if you have only one restaurant per owner and one owner per restaurant (and it looks like that, when you say that changing author works) you could define restaurant info as a set of fields at user's profile itself. That way each user would be able to edit his own data, and data of his restaurant, and you can use views to decide what to show and where.

Answer (score 0):

The [Node access user reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module lets you control who can edit what by means of a user reference, so I suggest you look at that as well. It's a more generic solution than Profile 2.